# Change github user in CMD Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, cmd

Right now, my command line is linked to my git account, "Account1".

I want to push to the repository owned by my other account, "Account2"

ex. Right now, when I `git push` I get:

```
remote: Permission to Account2/DesiredRepo denied to Account1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Account2/DesiredRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I login to my other account on cmd to push to that repository? I want something like:

`git logout`

`git login`
//Prompts login page of some sort to switch account

I haven't found any solutions so far that work well with windows.

Answer (score 0):

Git has no concept of authentication, so there are no `git logout` and `git login` commands. Instead, this is implemented by the protocol used to communicate with a remote. When you installed Git on Windows, you likely accepted the default settings, which includes enabling [Git Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/set-up-credential-managers). The first time you entered your GitHub user name and password, this tool stored them (hopefully securely) for use during future sessions. I assume it will allow you to manage your digital identities. You can read this documentation and research further how to switch accounts with this tool.

Alternatively, you can create SSH keys for each account. Add your public keys to the associated account then use the correct private key for authentication. Details are available on the GitHub help pages and documentation.